# Does juggling faster less work then juggling slower?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, velocity

I got this idea when juggling. Let's say three balls with the standard technique.
When I throw the balls higher it is harder (more work), but since it takes more time for them to fall back I work less often. When juggling faster, I throw the balls with less speed, but more often. Can you come up with a formula for this? How does the work of my arms depend on the height of the thrown ball?

Comment: Before you hoist a ball to a height, it falls into your hand from the same height, so in principle it takes zero work for any height. So it all depends on how efficient your muscles and joints are.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that as long as they are both constantly being juggled that it would be the same, because throwing a ball in the air at twice the speed will result in twice the time to fall, but also twice the work to achieve the speed. I'm just using deductive reasoning and some of the basics i have learned. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a few simplifying assumptions. We'll use only one ball, and assume that when the ball returns to your hand you immediately throw it back up - we'll assume the time taken for the throw is short enough to be ignored. We'll also assume your arm isn't elastically storing energy, so for each throw you have to put in fresh energy from your muscles. Finally we'll ignore the energy you need to stop the ball when you catch it, so we'll just calculate the energy needed to send it back up again.

Now suppose you throw the ball upwards at a velocity $v$. The energy you need to put in is the kinetic energy:

$$ E = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 $$

To find out how long the ball stays in the air we use the SUVAT equation:

$$ v = u + at $$

In this case the initial velocity is $+v$ (we'll take up to be positive) and the final velocity is $-v$, and the acceleration $a$ is the acceleration due to gravity, $-g$. So:

$$ -v = +v - gt $$

And a quick rearrangement gives:

$$ t = \frac{2v}{g} $$

The power required, $P$, is just the energy divided by the time, so:

$$ P = \frac{E}{t} = \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2}{\frac{2v}{g}} = \tfrac{1}{4}mgv $$

So the power you need to supply is linearly proportion to the speed you throw the ball.